# How to remove underline using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Coding Progress</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
</head>


<body>

  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Coding Path</h1>
      <h2>HTML CSS</h2>

    </header>

    <p>
        Computer programming is the process of performing a particular computation, usually by 
        designing and building an executable computer program.
        Programming involves tasks such as analysis, generating algorithms, profiling algorithms' 
        accuracy and resource consumption, and the implementation of algorithms.
    </p>

    <p>
      For young learners, programming helps to gain problem-solving skills i.e. to solve a problem in a logical as well as creative way. 
      Coding also enhances thinking ability and enables one to think logically, strategically, and analytically.
    </p>
    <br>
    

    <footer>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/realmilanez">
        <img src="./images/Dubai.png" alt="Dubai, Burj Khalifa">
      </a>

      <br><br>
      <q style="font-size:13px;">Make it work, make it right, make it fast.</q>

    </footer>


  </article>




</body>


</html>
```

Currently, I am able to operate with .css finally, however, when I hover my mouse on the picture, it creates a red underline on the right side of it. How am I able to mark the exact image and make the program ignore the underline, so only the border becomes white while hovering...

Here's the code in .CSS:

```css
a:link {
  color            : green;
  background-color : transparent;
  text-decoration  : none;
  }
a:visited {
  color            : pink;
  background-color : transparent;
  text-decoration  : none;
  }
a:hover {
  color            : red;
  background-color : transparent;
  text-decoration  : underline;
  }
a:active {
  color            : yellow;
  background-color : transparent;
  text-decoration  : underline;
  }
footer a:hover img, 
footer a:active img {
  color           : white;
  border-color    : white;
  text-decoration : none;
}  

  body {
    color:rgb(240,240,240);
    background: rgb(27,39,51);
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    }


  footer img {
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 70%;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    }


  h1, h2, h3 {
    margin:0;
    }


  h2 {
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 8px;
    }


  h1, strong, em {
    
    color: orange;
    }

  
  article {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    max-width: 420px;
  }
```

The image does not remove the red underline even though the code says to remove the decoration in the last last section

[The problem is shown here<----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPb7w.png)

Comment: Please include both your HTML and your CSS code, preferably as a working snippet.

Comment: `footer a:hover img` applies to the image `a:hover` applies to the link as a whole. The image will have no underline but the link will. Any white space in the link will get an underline. If you want to remove the underline from all inks in the footer use `footer a:hover, footer a:active`

Comment: Exactly, however I want to remove that underline from the picture, so it becomes white, but not with that underline on the right side.

Comment: Please inlcude your HTML, preferably as a [MCVE] so we can get a better picture of your problem.

Comment: We need your HTML, not more CSS. **Your HTML will provide vital context**.

Comment: @JonP I have done it.

Comment: I have found the mistake </footer> was not closed after I added the src
So basically I should have close the tag right after I finished with </a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
footer a:hover, footer a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the full .css style, but it does not work in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
<footer>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/realmilanez">
        <img src="./images/Dubai.png" alt="Dubai, Burj Khalifa">
      </a>
    </footer>
```

I did it wrong and I should have closed the `</footer>` after that, however I added following code inside of it and it did not work just because of that.

```
<br><br>
   <q style="font-size:13px;">Make it work, make it right, make it fast.</q>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey @realmilanez I edit your code and run the browser then I fixed this issue you can look at the css added this code in your stylesheet I comment this code.

```css
a:link {
    color            : green;
    background-color : transparent;
    text-decoration  : none;
    }
  a:visited {
    color            : pink;
    background-color : transparent;
    text-decoration  : none;
    }
  a:hover {
    color            : red;
    background-color : transparent;
    text-decoration  : underline;
    }
  a:active {
    color            : yellow;
    background-color : transparent;
    text-decoration  : underline;
    }
  footer a:hover>img, 
  footer a:active img {
    color           : white;
    border-color    : white;
    text-decoration : none;
  }  

  /* added this code in your stylesheet */
  footer a:hover {
    text-decoration : none;
  }  

  
    body {
      color:rgb(240,240,240);
      background: rgb(27,39,51);
      font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      }
  
  
    footer img {
      width: 80px;
      border-radius: 70%;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      }
  
  
    h1, h2, h3 {
      margin:0;
      }
    h2 {
      font-size:16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 8px;
      }
  
  
    h1, strong, em {
      
      color: orange;
      }
    article {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 50px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      max-width: 420px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Coding Progress</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
</head>


<body>

  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Coding Path</h1>
      <h2>HTML CSS</h2>

    </header>

    <p>
        Computer programming is the process of performing a particular computation, usually by 
        designing and building an executable computer program.
        Programming involves tasks such as analysis, generating algorithms, profiling algorithms' 
        accuracy and resource consumption, and the implementation of algorithms.
    </p>

    <p>
      For young learners, programming helps to gain problem-solving skills i.e. to solve a problem in a logical as well as creative way. 
      Coding also enhances thinking ability and enables one to think logically, strategically and analytically.
    </p>
    <br>
    

    <footer>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/realmilanez">
        <img src="./images/Dubai.png" alt="Dubai, Burj Khalifa">
      </a>

      <br><br>
      <q style="font-size:13px;">Make it work, make it right, make it fast.</q>

    </footer>


  </article>




</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```